# How can I fit this UPDATE query into this existing SELECT statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, subquery

I have an existing stored procedure.  I have been asked to attempt to find a way to fit a specific set of logic into the procedure in order to avoid having to create a new one.  However, I am not the best with SQL, but I would still like to do everything I can to accomplish my task.

My current goal: use the existing table generated from the select top 400 statement and somehow fit the update I wrote (second chunk of code) to work with that.

My existing procedure:

```
USE [cph]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER proc [dbo].[PatientSynch]
    @EnvironmentKey varchar(1)
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @patId VARCHAR(25)

    select top 400 
        c.pat_id as cpPatId,
        (LEFT(c.fname, 1)
            +LEFT(c.lname, 1) 
            + @EnvironmentKey 
            + RIGHT('00000000' 
            + convert(varchar,c.pat_id),8 )) AS PRN,
        c.pref_meth_cont_cn as PreferredChannel
        --,p.cppatid,p.prn 
    from 
        dbo.cppat c 
        left outer join dbo.patient p on c.pat_id=p.cppatid
    where 
        p.cppatid is null or p.prn is null
    order by 
        c.pat_id desc

END
```

The statement I have created to suit my needs:

```
UPDATE dbo.cppat
SET chart_id = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), pat_id) + '+'
WHERE pat_id IN
(
    SELECT pat_id
    FROM cppat
)
```

Comment: This must not be the whole procedure. You have the patId variable which isn't used and your existing select statement has a syntax error in it. Unless you provide some details about what you are really trying to do there is little to nothing anybody can do to help here.

Comment: I've slightly modified the procedure to remove some company information related to db names.  It shouldn't hugely impact much.

There should be enough info there to get the basic idea of what I'm trying to do though.

Comment: I get that you want to obfuscate some stuff that isn't an issue. The problem is that it isn't clear what you are trying to do. Are you want to update only the same 400 rows as you have in the above select statement? If so, just add the same query to your update statements subquery.

Comment: Yes, essentially.  I want to use the results of the Select 400 statement and modify those results using the Update statement.  Basically, the 400 rows returned will contain a column called cpPatId.  I want to take the value of cpPatId, add the string '+' to the end and store that value in the column chart_id.  The select 400 must be done first as this is part of a daemon process, but I'm trying to kill two birds with one stone.  I do not know where I can possibly add my Update to my existing select to do so.

Comment: Additionally, this is a stored proc so I can just add the update statement in a separate query in the same proc, but I'd prefer to get it done all in one query, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by I want to select and update in one query? a query is either an update query or a select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added Chart_id in the query since you need it there to update it.  This creates a common table expression that you can use to update records.

```
;WITH Update_Complex_Query AS
(
  SELECT TOP 400
      c.pat_id AS cpPatId
      , (LEFT(c.fname, 1) + LEFT(c.lname, 1) + @EnvironmentKey + + RIGHT('00000000' + convert(VARCHAR, c.pat_id), 8)) AS PRN
      , c.pref_meth_cont_cn AS PreferredChannel
  --,p.cppatid,p.prn 
    , c.Chart_Id
  FROM dbo.cppat c
  LEFT JOIN dbo.patient p
      ON c.pat_id = p.cppatid
  WHERE p.cppatid IS NULL
      OR p.prn IS NULL
  ORDER BY c.pat_id DESC
)
UPDATE Update_Complex_Query
SET Chart_id = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cpPatId) + '+'
```